# FPDF Unicode Support using UFPDF

Tags: php, unicode, fpdf

I am struggeling around a long time with this and I suspect other users do as well.

First I have to say that I have no alternative to FPDF because I use a lot of other FPDF modules, so please try not to recommend to use another library Like TCPDF.

I really need to make FPDF to be able to handle UTF-8 characters in a stable way.

**What I already found out:**

There is an extension called UFPDF 
http://acko.net/blog/ufpdf-unicode-utf-8-extension-for-fpdf/

The extension supports TrueType fonts only for now but it should work for me.
The .ttf file has to be converted by a tool called ttf2ufm and the resulting .ufm and the source .ttf are convertet to font.php, font.z and font.ctg.z file by using the given tool makefontuni.php.

So far so good. So I tried to convert the Arial font from my computer. (arial.ttf, arialbd.ttf, arialbi.ttf, ariali.ttf)

It worked and I was able to produce a test.pdf with unicode characters. But the was a error popup shown by AdobeReader which says something like: Bad Parameter - the font ArialMT contains bad /Widths.

I noticed that all characters had the same width (i suspect the default widths) so I tried to debug.

I found out that UPDF adds the widths to the PDF like this:

```
charnumber [width] charnumber [width]

85 [276] (for the "u" character)
```

And I found out that some characters had a negative index value:

```
-70 [266]
```

The index values are created by ttf2ufm. If i look at the resulting arial.ufm i found entries like this:

```
U -70 ; WX 450 ; N uni06BE ; G 1003 ; B -70 256 788 1136 ;
```

I suspected that U is the index in utf-8 table and I modified the makefontuni.php to make it to ignore negative values for U. Created the font.php, font.z and font.ctg.z again and it worked. The Error-Notice was not shown and the characters was shown up with the correct width.

**So the first question is:** 
Why does ttf2ufm produce negative values for U? Is this correct? And if it is correct why is the AdobeReader not able to handle it?

I hoped that was all but it is not.

I did some more tests by using the BOLD font and the lower "u" character was shown as a strange sign when using arial bold.

I debugged again and I found this line for the "u" character in arialbd.ufm

```
U 117 ; WX 611 ; N u ; G 88 ; B 141 -24 1107 1062 ;
```

I searched for "U 117" in that file and I found another character beginning with "U 117 ;". I already removed it so I cannot post the line here. However this was the wrong char shown in pdf and after removing it the u had been displayed correctly.

**So the second question is:** What is the reason why ttf2ufm produces a .ufm file with 2 characters with the same index? This happens only for arialbd.ttf not for arial.ttf.

However i solved it for now hoping there are no other double-index-characters.

More issues:

I recognized that the resulting arial.php contains the character widths:

```
$cw=array(
    32=>278, 160=>278, 33=>278, 34=>355, 35=>556, 36=>556, 
    37=>889, 38=>667, 39=>191, 40=>333, 41=>333, 42=>389, 43=>584, 
    44=>278, 45=>333, 173=>333, [...]
```

The arial.php in non-unicode version contains the `$cw` array, too. But it uses the character itself as index, not the index number:

```
$cw=array(  
    chr(0)=>750,chr(1)=>750,chr(2)=>750,chr(3)=>750,chr(4)=>750,
    chr(5)=>750,chr(6)=>750,chr(7)=>750,chr(8)=>750,chr(9)=>750,chr(10)=>750,
    chr(11)=>750,chr(12)=>750, [...]
```

And fpdf.php sometimes tries to access the `$cw` value and some other modules do it, too to be able to compute the width of given string. All of this failed for UFPDF.

I tried to fix it by modify fpdf.php and all modules that try to access `$cw` like this:

I created a method called `charlength` in fpdf class:

```
function charlength($char) 
{
    $cw = &$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    return $cw[$char];
}
```

And made FPDF to call `charlength` whenever it wants to access `$this->CurrentFont['cw']`:

```
function GetStringWidth($s)
{
    // Get width of a string in the current font
    $s = (string)$s;
    // $cw = &$this->CurrentFont['cw']; // Old FPDF-Code
    $w = 0;
    $l = strlen($s);
    for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++) {
        // $w += $cw[$s[$i]]; // Old FPDF-Code
        $w += $this->charlength($s[$i]); // My replacement
    }
    return $w*$this->FontSize/1000;
}
```

In ufpdf.php i override the method `charlength` like this:

```
function charlength($char) {    
    $cw = &$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    $utf8dec = $this->ordutf8($char, $offset);        
    if(!isset($cw[$utf8dec])) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $cw[$utf8dec];
}


function ordutf8($string, &$offset) {
    $string = class_stringTools::utf8_decode($string);
    $code = ord(substr($string, $offset,1));
    if ($code >= 128) {        //otherwise 0xxxxxxx
        if ($code < 224) $bytesnumber = 2;                //110xxxxx
        else if ($code < 240) $bytesnumber = 3;        //1110xxxx
        else if ($code < 248) $bytesnumber = 4;    //11110xxx
        else return -1;
        $codetemp = $code - 192 - ($bytesnumber > 2 ? 32 : 0) - ($bytesnumber > 3 ? 16 : 0);
        for ($i = 2; $i <= $bytesnumber; $i++) {
            $offset ++;
            $code2 = ord(substr($string, $offset, 1)) - 128;        //10xxxxxx
            $codetemp = $codetemp*64 + $code2;
        }
        $code = $codetemp;
    }
    $offset += 1;
    if ($offset >= strlen($string)) $offset = -1;
    return $code;
}
```

The `ordutf8` method is from php.net but i had to modify it because i got strage values for `$code` one time the value of `$code` was 252 which results in an undefined `$bytenumber`.

However it seems to work for now but I am not very happy with editing the source of fpdf.php and the source of other modules. And I am wondering that nobody else reports the issues i struggled with.

I know i have written very much but i want to know if everyone had the same issues. What do you think about the last modifications? Do you have some improvements? I really need a stable way to make FPDF to support unicode characters. Please help me.

It is a shame that the author of ufpdf has no time to support this.

Comment: Did you also checked [tFPDF](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) ? It supports UTF-8 and font subsetting. Works great for left-to-right languages.

Comment: This is supposed to be the question but I've learnt so much from it! I like your thought flow, clarity in explaining and attention to detail. Do you have a blog I can follow?

Comment: Just as @JanSlabon mentioned, I believe **tFPDF** will solve your problem, since it can work directly with the .ttf font files without you having to do the intermediate conversions on them

Comment: @JeromyAdofo thank you very much for your feedback. I've written this 10 years ago and I am surprised about my clarity, too! I use tcpdf now which has a full utf8-support.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jan Slabon mentioned in the comment, [tFPDF library](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) (ie. FPDF script 92) should work for you. Since tFPDF directly processes the .ttf font files, it avoids the need for the intermediate conversions, and you will likely not have challenges with the character width indices.

According to the library header, my current version is 1.33 (based on FPDF 1.85).